# Assigning Array to new variable, changing original changes the new one

Tags: java, arrays

```
int[] test = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] before = test;
    System.out.println(before[2]);
    test[2] = 65;
    System.out.println(before[2]);
```

The first System.out prints **2** and it should, but the second prints **65**. I have been programming for over a year in this language and as far as I know this is NOT suppose to happen! Any help?

```
    int first = 9;
    int second = first;
    System.out.println(second);
    first = 10;
    System.out.println(second);
```

The code above prints **9** on both lines.

Comment: In both cases this is working as expected. You are assigning values to variables and they are printing values they are assigned to. I hope you are not confusing between C style references (int *) to Java.

Comment: I do not know C, in fact Java is the only one i use. Thankfully I ran into this problem on a leisurely project, and not something important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `before = test;`, before is just a reference to `test` array, **NO** new array has been created and assigned to `test`. So when you look the value of `before[i]` you basically look at the value of `test[i]` and vice versa. `before` is just an alias of `test`. That's why in the second print you get 65.

Check this [text](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ306_015.htm) from **Thinking in Java** book, it will definitely help you.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not expect this to happen. You are simply **assigning** two variables to the same array, and then You are assigning index #2 *of that array* as 65, so, you should get 65 the next time you print what's on index #2.

see examples at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior. If you want to copy an array then you need to copy it.

```
class ArrayCopyDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] copyFrom = { 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'e',
                'i', 'n', 'a', 't', 'e', 'd' };
        char[] copyTo = new char[7];

        System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 2, copyTo, 0, 7);
        System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
    }
}
```

via http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

For the int's, you are correct they do not reference each other. But when you use an array, they are considered objects, so when you did the `before = test`, in memory they are pointing to the same object.